# How can I scan my generated QR Code in laravel jetstream?

Tags: laravel, qr-code, laravel-jetstream, instascan

How can I scan my generated QR Code in laravel?
When I try to scan my generated code, nothing happens, and I want it to be save to the database.
I want to display the data from the generated QR code in the table
These are my codes for generation of QR Code:

```
            // AdminController.php

            public function emailview_approved($id)
            {
            $appointment = Appointment::find($id);

            $data = [
            'name' => $appointment->name,
            'date' => $appointment->date,
            'department' => $appointment->department_name,
            ];

            $qrCode = generateQRCode($appointment);
            // Update the appointment status
            $appointment->status = 'Approved';
            $appointment->save();

            $appointment = Appointment::find($id);

            return view('admin.email_view_approved', compact('appointment', 'qrCode'));
            }
```

Comment: I don't see your code even attempting to save the qr code into your db.

Comment: yes, the qr codes are saved on the public folder. I mean, the data from the qr code I want it to scan, display on table, and save on the database.